# Alternatives to GROUP BY/HAVING using MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, sqlfiddle

I am faced with the following problem:

> Come up with a query that lists the people(pname) who own more than one car (you cannot use GROUP BY and/or HAVING)
>
> Use the following database schema:
>
> vehicle (licplate*, year, make, model, cost, pname)

Here's the query I would like to use

```
select pname from vehicle
group by pname
having count(*) > 1;
```

I have been trying to come up with a way to do this as per the specifications but I haven't had any success. Could someone guide me through the logic of doing this?

Thank you for reading.

Comment: what is the specific reason to not use Groupby and Having? 
"you cannot use GROUP BY and/or HAVING"

Comment: Is there perhaps a flaw in assigning pname as a PK?

Comment: It's just part of the practice question.  I think the reason is just to practice

Comment: Anyway, a simple join will suffice

Comment: @Strawberry I believe so as well, since there could be multiple people with the same name, but its just a practice question so I don't ponder too much over it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select * from 
    (select *, 
        if (@name= pname, 1,0) as flag,
        @name:= pname as pn
     from vehicle
     order by pname) sub
where sub.flag=1;
```

[SQL fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/171fe6/2)

We may also add DISTINCT to cover cases when there are more than 2 cars

UPDATED:

```
Select *
from vehicle v1
     join vehicle v2 on v1.pname=v2.pname 
                        and (v1.id!=v2.id)
```

Instead of v1.id!=v2.id you can add Primary Key checks PK of v1 !=PK of v2

Comment: I see...
We had used this aliasing method before, I don't know how I didn't see it.  Maybe I'm just overcomplicating these queries.
Thank you @StanislavL

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried using [Subquery](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/subqueries.html) ?

Using your table as reference, it should be like this

```
SELECT 
p.pname
FROM person AS p
WHERE
(SELECT count(*) FROM vehicle where pname = p.pname) > 1
```

Comment: I think this is rather contrary to the spirit of the question. Also, as this is homework, it seems a little indecent to provide a complete answer.

Comment: i just tried to fulfill the question requirements about not to use HAVING and/or GROUP BY condition. Anyway, you can achieve same result using DISTINCT and JOIN..

Comment: @Strawberry I apologize but I wasn't looking for a straight answer.  I'm looking for advice or guidance on this.  Thank you

Comment: @Sektrax And you've found it

Comment: @Moch. Rasyid The query that was provided as the answer displays all the names in the person table whereas I only have two individuals who own more than one vehicle.  I'm not sure I understand why the condition in the where clause checks for the count the way it does.

Comment: @Sektrax query above should display only individuals that own more than one vehicle.. for the where condition, it's a sub query to count owned car  by using pname from person table as a key..